# Searching on an array of array of dictionaries by a key

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have dictionaries like this

```
  NSDictionary *dictA = @{ @"name" : @"John",
                           @"city" : @"Los Angeles" };

  NSDictionary *dictB = @{ @"name" : @"Bob",
                           @"city" : @"Los Angeles" };

  NSDictionary *dictC = @{ @"name" : @"Carl",
                           @"city" : @"Dallas" };
```

Dozens of dictionaries like this were separated by city and put inside other dictionaries like

```
  NSArray *losAngeles = @[ dictA, dictB, ....];

  NSArray *dallas = @[ dictC, ... ];
```

and everything is inside an array

```
self.arrayAll = @[losAngeles, dallas, miami... ];
```

now the better part, I want to get a the dictionary that contains the person named Bob (suppose all names are unique).

If that was an array of dicts I would do this

```
  NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@)", @"Bob"];
  NSarray *filteredNames = [self.arrayAll filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

But because arrayAll is an array of array of dicts, this is not working with the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string ????

any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it something like this...

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

[citiesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSArray *dictArray, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@)", @"Bob"];
    NSArray *filteredNames = [self.arrayAll filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

    [results addObjectsFromArray:filteredNames];
}];
```

You could possibly add the concurrency option like this...

```
[citiesArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(NSArray *dictArray, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    //stuff...
}];
```

To have it run concurrently too. I don't know how the results array would handle that though. Give it a try.

This will exploit the fast enumeration and concurrency for all steps.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do a fast enumeration?
Something like:

```
for (NSArray *cityArray in self.arrayAll) {

   for (NSDictionary *cityDictionary in cityArray) {

    if ([[cityDictionary valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"Bob"]) {
      //do something
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I was thinking of this too, but isn't that super-heavy for the device?

Comment: No. This kind of enumeration happens all the time in different frameworks but concurrently. I suggest you do this on a different thread and if you need to update the UI from it just call the main thread.